# How to add UIBarButton Programmatically to navBar of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I want to add a `UIBarButton` to the "navBar" of the `viewController`.
Here's my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ Contact"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:self
                                                            action:@selector(showPicker:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```

Nothing shows up on the "navBar". I also tried adding it through the storyboard but I couldn't connect it to the interface of my `viewController` as an `IBAction`.

Can't figure it out.

Comment: Your code will only work if the view controller in a navigation controller.